# Web scrape will not return the correct text data

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I'm trying to scape a simple table from the Second Hand Songs website. I'm using the following code and `rvest` package in R.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

levee_breaks_url <- html('https://secondhandsongs.com/performance/17982')

levee_breaks_url %>% 
  html_node('.field-performer') %>% 
  html_text()
```

Which returns

```
[1] "Performer "
```

My goal is to get a list of all information in the tables on the page. I've tried including `html_node('.container')`, but the result is not correct.

I'm using the `selector gadget` and have been successful with it at scraping other websites, but I've been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try. This will scrape all the tables, combine them, then give columns the correct names.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

levee_breaks_url <- read_html('https://secondhandsongs.com/performance/17982')

df <- levee_breaks_url %>% 
  html_nodes('.table') %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  reduce(rbind) %>%
  select(-1) %>%
  rename_all(~levee_breaks_url %>% 
               html_nodes('th') %>% 
               html_text() %>% 
               .[2:5]) %>%
  as.tibble()

df
#> # A tibble: 32 x 4
#>    `Title `       `Performer `         `Release date `  Info              
#>    <chr>          <chr>                <chr>            <chr>             
#>  1 When the Leve… Kansas Joe and Memp… 1929             First release     
#>  2 When the Leve… John Campbell        February 20, 19… ""                
#>  3 When the Leve… Clint Black          2005             ""                
#>  4 When the Leve… Bennett Harris       August 27, 2008  ""                
#>  5 When the Leve… Buckwheat Zydeco     2009             ""                
#>  6 Levee Breaks   Beverley Martyn      April 2014       ""                
#>  7 When the Leve… Danny B. Harvey - M… October 14, 2014 ""                
#>  8 When the Leve… Led Zeppelin         November 8, 1971 First releaseSamp…
#>  9 When the Leve… Judge                1990             ""                
#> 10 When the Leve… Rosetta Stone        October 14, 1991 Unverified        
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

Created on 2018-09-06 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask how you knew to use '.table'? Is this standard when scraping a website that has data in table format? Also, thanks for tidying up the data!

Comment: No problem. No, I don't think it is standard (I'm no expert though), I used the selector gadget and clicked around until I got something to work. Thats my typical attack strategy with web scraping.